# Convert row values into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE StatusStats (
    UserID      VARCHAR(50),
    StatusCategory  VARCHAR(50),
    StatusDuration  INT
)
```

That contains, for each user, how much time they were (StatusCategory)

- Productive
- NonProductive
- Unknown

(fyi... status duration is in seconds)

Those are the only 3 values.

In order to use this data in reporting using JOINs to other tables, I need to copy that data in to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE StatusStatsByUser (
    UserID      VARCHAR(50),
        Productive      INT,
        NonProductive   INT,
        Unknown         INT
)
```

That will contain in each column the value that was in the StatusDuration column for the corresponding value in the StatusCategory column.

I can't figure out how to write the SQL code to do that, using SQL Server 2008R2. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you reviewed the [many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+rows+to+columns) on this site about converting rows to columns? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Pondlife I saw a few but they all dealt with a dynamic quantity of columns. I though static would be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to store this data in a table, you can easily create a view that `PIVOT`s the data into the columns that you need:

```
CREATE VIEW yourPivotedView
AS 
select userid, Productive, NonProductive, Unknown
from 
(
    select userid, StatusCategory, StatusDuration
    from StatusStats 
) src
pivot
(
    sum(StatusDuration)
    for StatusCategory in (Productive, NonProductive, Unknown)
) piv
```

Once this is in a view, then you can join on it with your other tables:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
inner join yourPivotedView p
  on t1.userid = p.userid
```

But if you must insert this into a new table, you can use:

```
insert into StatusStatsByUser (userid, Productive, NonProductive, Unknown)
select userid, Productive, NonProductive, Unknown
from 
(
    select userid, StatusCategory, StatusDuration
    from StatusStats 
) src
pivot
(
    sum(StatusDuration)
    for StatusCategory in (Productive, NonProductive, Unknown)
) piv
```

Comment: I used the one that actually inserts because all this is in a stored procedure, and using runtime table. But, it's not working. It only populates the value in the first column, 'Productive'. The others are NULL for all rows.

Comment: @Amarundo can you post some sample data from your table? Or create a sql fiddle -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ -- with your data model

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
INSERT INTO StatusStatsByUser
SELECT  UserId ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN StatusCategory = 'Productive' THEN StatusDuration
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS Productive ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN StatusCategory = 'NonProductive' THEN StatusDuration
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS NonProductive ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN StatusCategory = 'Unknown' THEN StatusDuration
                 ELSE 0
            END) AS Unknown
FROM StatusStats
GROUP BY UserId
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the other answer, and I can only chose 1!